# MicroSD card stuck after CMD8, responding 0x5 before next CMD is issued

Tags: spi, sd

I have a problem for which I can't find the solution in previous topics.

I'm using a microcontroller to read data from a Kodak 2GB Micro SD Card. I want to write a minimal driver in SPI mode, no need to do writing or formatting operations, just read some files.

I can see those signals on a 4 channel scope: CS, MOSI, MISO, CLK.

I do the following:

1. I send 100 bytes at 100KHz, with MOSI and CS high.
2. I send CMD 1, no argument, response type R1 returns 0x1, correct.
3. I send CMD 8, arg=0x1AA, response type R7 returns 0x1+ arg 0x1AA, correct.
4. At this point every command returns 0x5 **at the 4th byte of the command**. In other words, before the 6 bytes command is completely issued.

Any explanation for that?

Comment: after sending the CMD8, you need to receive 8 bytes of data from SPI. isn't it?

Comment: I would say 6 bytes:dummy+response+4bytes(echo of argument).

Comment: Oops. Yeah. My bad

Answer (score 1):

In the last hour i did other test ...
Seems solved.
The difference is that before,when i wanted to to bang out the clock pulses necessary for read each command answer,**i did not pay particular attention on the data sent on MOSI** ,it was **0x00**.
Now i use **0xFF** and everything works fine.